# Sony Vaio VPCEA24FM not exhaust in Fan Vent

Tags: fan, cooling, sony-vaio, cpu-cooler

Sony Vaio VPCEA24FM resting on a Belkin cooling pad (which is very poor product). CPU heating up quite quickly.
No air coming out of the air exhaust vent tested with the back of hand, tried feeling air on the cheek. Looks like fan is working, noise is quite clearly auidable.  Below image of SpeedFan test.

1. Can I be sure that fan is still working?
2. If yes, why I cannot feel any exhaust air?

[image]

Comment: Dust buildup in the heat sink?

Comment: @LilCodger Amy suggestion for solution? Warranty expired. 3 year old.

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth: http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docTypeID=DT_KNOWLEDGEARTICLES_1_1&docType=kc&externalId=C1006888  If you're up to it we can check for a service manual and crack the sucker open.

Comment: @LilCodger Yes..yes I want to do it...i want to open it...

Comment: Having trouble finding that one, as Sony is quite stingy. Here's a Youtube tear-down of one though: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3CYuDh-S5A

Comment: @LilCodger Will do. Will need a set of screw-drivers. Please aggregate your comments a answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the age and the description, I would guess you have dust buildup in the CPU heat sink.

You can try using a vacuum/shopvac to suck it out, but for best results open the notebook up and clean out everything.

A teardown video is at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3CYuDh-S5A. Sony is unfortunately stingy with the service manuals (money in service).

Have some compressed air, likely a #0 Phillips screwdriver, and if possible some Arctic Silver. Since you'll be in there anyway it's probably worth replacing the CPU thermal grease.